# Divergent condition of a series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

For $s>0$ when the following series will diverge $$\sum_{k=1}\bigg(\frac{2^k}{1+2^k}\bigg)^{2s}.$$

Comment: We would love to see your attempts too, try some manipulation of terms.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what happens to the summand as $k$ gets large?

Comment: Can you say more??

Comment: Look up the divergence test.